# I'd like to install and configure the 'Checkpoint VPN' on Linux Mint. How can I do that?

Tags: linux, vpn, linux-mint, checkpoint

I'd like to install and configure the 'Checkpoint VPN' app on Linux Mint. How can I do that?. CheckPoint VPN is a windows app.

I already tried with winehq software. But "check point VPN" app can not install on it?